# Why doesn't this localhost cookie get set in the browser?

Tags: cookies, setcookie

In a server I'm building I want to set a cookie with an auth token that gets set when the user logs in. The login request is a POST XHR with a form containing my username and password. I'm testing this on `http://localhost:3000`.

I can see that the server is trying to set the cookie because the response has this header:

```
set-cookie: token=json-web-token-value;Expires=Fri, 12 Mar 2021 18:19:12 GMT
```

However Chrome seems to be ignoring this. No subsequent requests to the API contain the cookie and it also isn't in the list of cookies for `http://localhost:3000` in the `Application -> Cookies` devtools section.

When I try to set the cookie with JS manually like

```
document.cookie = 'token=json-web-token-value;Expires=Fri, 12 Mar 2021 18:19:12 GMT'
```

then the cookie does get set correctly. So the problem clearly isn't with the contents of the cookie itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT: Firefox**

I decided to check whether Firefox works any differently, and lo and behold the cookie does get set. The only thing that seemed odd is that the path was set to `/auth` – possibly because the login endpoint path is `/auth/login`. Setting the path in my server to `/` manually results in a cookie of

```
token=json-web-token-value;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 12 Mar 2021 18:34:27 GMT
```

which now seems to work even in Chrome!

So now my questions are:

1. Why does leaving the path undefined make Chrome completely ignore the cookie?
2. Why does not specifying a path make Firefox set the path to `/auth` and not `/`, or `/auth/login` for that matter?

Comment: Hello. I just posted a question that is very similar to yours here. Did you ever figure this out? One difference for me is neither Chrome nor Firefox work. Here's the question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791605/net-core-cross-site-cookie-not-being-set-by-chrome-or-firefox